# Analyze csv file with awk

Tags: linux, bash, shell, csv, awk

I need to analyze one csv file from an other csv file in which we can find some  " key words "

The csv file that I need to analyze looks like this, 4 columns and X rows :

```
NO1,NF_B000014,81920,23290,28,20480,22211,108,-16,0,100000000,none,online,fds,45501,none,Alo1,
NO1,N_000000,81920,63,0,20480,68,0,0,0,2464966,none,online,fds,131,none,Alo1,
NO1,NO_VM31_GRERW0I2_B000002,203162,87,0,50790,142,0,0,0,100000000,none,online,fds,229,none,Alo1,
NO1,NF_B000014,81920,23290,28,20480,22211,108,-16,0,100000000,none,online,fds,45501,none,Alo1,
NO1,NG_VM31_B000001,2347,54,0,432,69,0,0,0,4397642,none,online,fds,98,none,Alo2,
NO1,NG_VM31_B000001,2342,61,0,64532,69,0,0,0,2346,none,online,fds,90,none,Alo2,
NO1,NG_VM31_B000001,78692,61,0,432,69,0,0,0,23498765,none,online,fds,23,none,Alo2,
NO1,NG_VM31_B000001,98725,61,0,2080357,69,0,0,0,98643,none,online,fds,4330,none,Alo2,
NO1,NG_VM31_B000001,2351,61,0,3424,69,0,0,0,5673,none,online,fds,43,none,Alo2,
NO1,NL_098JD,51551,7,0,234,31,1,0,0,100000001,none,online,fds,99,none,Alo3,
NO1,NL_098JD,5145622,7,0,542,31,1,0,0,100000002,none,online,fds,99,none,Alo3,
NO1,NL_098JD,5123453,7,0,2714,31,1,0,0,100000003,none,online,fds,99,none,Alo3,
NO1,NL_098JD,51454,7,0,8567,31,1,0,0,100000004,none,online,fds,38,none,Alo3,
NO1,NL_098JD,515,7,0,532,31,1,0,0,100000005,none,online,fds,31,none,Alo3,
NO1,NL_098JD,51554,7,0,9347,31,1,0,0,100000006,none,online,fds,3812,none,Alo3,
NO1,NV_IUDS,19873,234,0,543,14,3,0,0,9869324,none,online,fds,54,none,Alo4,
NO1,NV_IUDS,32981,654,0,543,14,3,0,0,2346,none,online,fds,57,none,Alo4,
NO1,NV_IUDS,123554,634,0,543,14,3,0,0,2347642,none,online,fds,86,none,Alo4,
NO1,NV_IUDS,124432,846,0,543,14,3,0,0,1434326,none,online,fds,12,none,Alo4,
NO1,NV_IUDS,234531,402,0,543,14,3,0,0,234645234,none,online,fds,62,none,Alo4,
NO1,NJ_000004,305562,57467,19,76390,102,0,0,0,100000000,none,online,oiu,57569,none,NA,
NO1,NK_O09AE8,421888,221682,53,105472,200,0,0,0,100000000,none,online,oiu,12345,none,NA,
NO1,NK_O09AE8,42188,221682,53,105472,200,0,0,0,100000000,none,online,oiu,221882,none,NA,
NO1,NK_O09AE8,421488,221682,53,105472,200,0,0,0,100000000,none,online,oiu,4325,none,NA,
NO1,NK_O09AE8,421845,221682,53,105472,200,0,0,0,100000000,none,online,oiu,9877634,none,NA,
NO1,NK_O09AE8,421234,221682,53,105472,200,0,0,0,100000000,none,online,oiu,22324882,none,NA,
NO1,NK_O09AE8,421643,221682,53,105472,200,0,0,0,100000000,none,online,oiu,234,none,NA,
NO1,NK_O09AE8,421231,221682,53,105472,200,0,0,0,100000000,none,online,oiu,9834,none,NA,
NO1,NK_O09AE8,421324,221682,53,105472,200,0,0,0,100000000,none,online,oiu,234,none,NA,
NO1,NK_O09AE8,421987,221682,53,105472,200,0,0,0,100000000,none,online,oiu,2345,none,NA,
NO1,NK_O09AE8,42134,221682,53,105472,200,0,0,0,100000000,none,online,oiu,6542,none,NA,
NO1,NF_B000014,81920,23290,28,20480,22211,108,-16,0,100000000,none,online,fds,45501,none,Alo5,
NO1,N_000000,81920,63,0,20480,68,0,0,0,2464966,none,online,fds,131,none,Alo5,
NO1,NO_VM31_GRERW0I2_B000002,203162,87,0,50790,142,0,0,0,100000000,none,online,fds,229,none,Alo5,
NO1,NF_B000014,81920,23290,28,20480,22211,108,-16,0,100000000,none,online,fds,45501,none,Alo5,
NO1,NG_VM31_B000001,2347,54,0,432,69,0,0,0,4397642,none,online,fds,98,none,Alo6,
NO1,NG_VM31_B000001,2342,61,0,64532,69,0,0,0,2346,none,online,fds,90,none,Alo6,
NO1,NG_VM31_B000001,78692,61,0,432,69,0,0,0,23498765,none,online,fds,23,none,Alo6,
NO1,NG_VM31_B000001,98725,61,0,2080357,69,0,0,0,98643,none,online,fds,4330,none,Alo6,
NO1,NG_VM31_B000001,2351,61,0,3424,69,0,0,0,5673,none,online,fds,43,none,Alo6,
NO1,NL_098JD,51551,7,0,234,31,1,0,0,100000001,none,online,fds,99,none,Alo7,
NO1,NL_098JD,5145622,7,0,542,31,1,0,0,100000002,none,online,fds,99,none,Alo7,
NO1,NL_098JD,5123453,7,0,2714,31,1,0,0,100000003,none,online,fds,99,none,Alo7,
NO1,NL_098JD,51454,7,0,8567,31,1,0,0,100000004,none,online,fds,38,none,Alo7,
NO1,NL_098JD,515,7,0,532,31,1,0,0,100000005,none,online,fds,31,none,Alo7,
NO1,NL_098JD,51554,7,0,9347,31,1,0,0,100000006,none,online,fds,3812,none,Alo7,
NO1,NV_IUDS,19873,234,0,543,14,3,0,0,9869324,none,online,fds,54,none,Alo8,
NO1,NV_IUDS,32981,654,0,543,14,3,0,0,2346,none,online,fds,57,none,Alo8,
NO1,NV_IUDS,123554,634,0,543,14,3,0,0,2347642,none,online,fds,86,none,Alo8,
NO1,NV_IUDS,124432,846,0,543,14,3,0,0,1434326,none,online,fds,12,none,Alo8,
NO1,NV_IUDS,234531,402,0,543,14,3,0,0,234645234,none,online,fds,62,none,Alo8,
NO1,NJ_000004,305562,57467,19,76390,102,0,0,0,100000000,none,online,oiu,57569,none,NA,
NO1,NK_O09AE8,421888,221682,53,105472,200,0,0,0,100000000,none,online,oiu,12345,none,NA,
NO1,NK_O09AE8,42188,221682,53,105472,200,0,0,0,100000000,none,online,oiu,221882,none,NA,
NO1,NK_O09AE8,421488,221682,53,105472,200,0,0,0,100000000,none,online,oiu,4325,none,NA,
NO1,NK_O09AE8,421845,221682,53,105472,200,0,0,0,100000000,none,online,oiu,9877634,none,NA,
NO1,NK_O09AE8,421234,221682,53,105472,200,0,0,0,100000000,none,online,oiu,22324882,none,NA,
NO1,NK_O09AE8,421643,221682,53,105472,200,0,0,0,100000000,none,online,oiu,234,none,NA,
NO1,NK_O09AE8,421231,221682,53,105472,200,0,0,0,100000000,none,online,oiu,9834,none,NA,
NO1,NK_O09AE8,421324,221682,53,105472,200,0,0,0,100000000,none,online,oiu,234,none,NA,
NO1,NK_O09AE8,421987,221682,53,105472,200,0,0,0,100000000,none,online,oiu,2345,none,NA,
NO1,NK_O09AE8,42134,221682,53,105472,200,0,0,0,100000000,none,online,oiu,6542,none,NA,
```

The csv file with my " key words " looks like this :

```
Alo1
Alo2
Alo3
Alo4
```

I need to develop a script that will extract all the lines of my csv file in which we can found  the words present in my csv file that contains my keywords.

I can do this with this script :

```
while read jour
do
        grep -wf "$1" "$2" | awk -F',' '{if(f!=$1)print"\n"; f=$1; print $0;}' | awk -F',' '{print $1","$2","$15","$17}' > test1.csv

done <"$1"
```

The result is :

```
NO1,NF_B000014,45501,Alo1
NO1,N_000000,131,Alo1
NO1,NO_VM31_GRERW0I2_B000002,229,Alo1
NO1,NF_B000014,45501,Alo1
NO1,NG_VM31_B000001,98,Alo2
NO1,NG_VM31_B000001,90,Alo2
NO1,NG_VM31_B000001,23,Alo2
NO1,NG_VM31_B000001,4330,Alo2
NO1,NG_VM31_B000001,43,Alo2
NO1,NL_098JD,99,Alo3
NO1,NL_098JD,99,Alo3
NO1,NL_098JD,99,Alo3
NO1,NL_098JD,38,Alo3
NO1,NL_098JD,31,Alo3
NO1,NL_098JD,3812,Alo3
NO1,NV_IUDS,54,Alo4
NO1,NV_IUDS,57,Alo4
NO1,NV_IUDS,86,Alo4
NO1,NV_IUDS,12,Alo4
NO1,NV_IUDS,62,Alo4
```

Can you show me how to do this with awk ? With NR, FNR etc ?

Thanks !

Comment: Where you say `The result is` - is that the actual output you get that you don't want or is it the output you DO want? If the latter then explain why `NO1,NO_VM31_GRERW0I2_B000002,229,` is present and why so many lines containing your key words are missing. If the former then add the latter. Also - are those words you want to find always just in your last field or can they appear anywhere in the line? Can they be part of longer strings or not?

Comment: @EdMorton Excuse me ! I give you the wrong file so yes, there was a mistake ! 
Yes, the words I want to find are always in the same field. I modified my post, this time, the examples are good! 

Thanks for your help ! :)

Comment: @Makmy I have updated my answer to reflect your edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to develop a script that will extract all the lines of my CSV file in which we can found the words present in my CSV file that contains my keywords.

So without any restriction where the word should appear:

```
$ grep -Fwf keywords.csv file.csv
```

**after edit:**

The following line in your script:

```
grep -wf "$1" "$2" | awk -F',' '{if(f!=$1)print"\n"; f=$1; print $0;}' | awk -F',' '{print $1","$2","$15","$17}' > test1.csv
```

Can be replaced by:

```
awk '### processing first file starts here
     # read the first file and store list in array a
     (NR==FNR){a[$1];next}
     ### processing second file starts here
     # initialize variables
     # - Set FS and OFS for file 2
     # - reprocess $0 with new FS ($0=$0)
     (FNR==1) { FS=OFS=","; $0=$0 }
     # if 17th field is in a, process
     # - initialize f if this is the first match
     # - print required fields and 
     # - prepend with ORS (\n) or empty string if $1 changed
     ($17 in a) { if (c++==0) f=$1
                  print (f != $1 ? ORS : "") $1,$2,$15,$17
                  f=$1
     }' "$1" "$2" > test1.csv
```

Details on `FS`, `OFS`, `NR`, `FNR` and `ORS` can be found [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html).

Comment: Damn ! That works well ! Thank you !
Last question : If possible, can you detail your awk for me, step by step?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like what you're trying to do:

```
$ awk -F', *' 'NR==FNR{words[$1];next} $NF in words' words file
ANA1,#DEFF24,99460, Alo1
ANA1,#DEFF43,15654,Alo1
ANA1,VM30_0009,587290,Alo4
ANA1,#DEFF29,99RS0, Alo2
ANA1,#DEFF43,18NCSO,Alo3
ANA1,VEZK_IOP,587290,Alo4
ANA1,#DEFF98,9846, Alo2
ANA1,#DEFF47,3476,Alo3
ANA1,VM323_LOp9,49862,Alo4
```

If not then edit your question to clarify your requirements and provide more truly representative sample input and expected output.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer ! I appreciate ! 
I modified my post and added the good examples!